# Heroku node timeout because of enormous task

Tags: node.js, heroku

Our node app gets quite big and one job takes quite some time to execute. We run this job with a cronjob, but by calling the URL. Now Heroku has problems with this, because the job takes more than 30 seconds to finish. So we receive a time-out and after that it tries to execute it immediately again, and again, till our Memory quota is about 300% and the app crashes.

Now I want to fix this. Locally we don't have any problems running this script at all. It takes about a minute (for now, but in the future if we have more users it may take more time) to finish and memory stays stable.

Now running this script on the background should fix the problem according https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#debugging-request-timeouts

Overe here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/asynchronous-web-worker-model-using-rabbitmq-in-node#getting-started I read about JackRabbit. But it seems like it's used for systems like RabbitMQ https://github.com/hunterloftis/jackrabbit

So my question: anyone who has experience with background tasks in node? Can and should I use JackRabbit for my background tasks, or are there better solutions? My background task just contains a very complex ExpressJS task, which takes some time to execute so....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the Node.js platform owner at Heroku (and I actually wrote the web worker article you referenced).

Your use case sounds like it may fit the scheduler very well:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

It's a great replacement for cron-type jobs.